# DataFrame Definintion is lazy evaluation

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, lazy-evaluation

I am new to spark and learning it. can someone help with below question

The quote in spark definitive regarding dataframe definition is "In general, Spark will fail only at job execution time rather than DataFrame definition time—even if,
for example, we point to a file that does not exist. This is due to lazy evaluation,"

so I guess `spark.read.format().load()` is dataframe definition. On top of this created dataframe we apply transformations and action and load is read API and not transformation if I am not wrong.

I tried to "file that does not exist" in load and I am thinking this is dataframe definition. but I got below error. according to the book it should not fail right?. I am surely missing something. can someone help on this?

```
df=spark.read.format('csv')
.option('header', 
'true').option('inferschema', 'true')
.load('/spark_df_data/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/retail-data/by-day/2011-12-19.csv')
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 166, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load(path))
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/lib/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1160, in __call__
  File "/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
    raise AnalysisException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u'Path does not exist: /spark_df_data/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/retail-data/by-day/2011-12-19.csv;'
```

why dataframe definition is referring Hadoop metadata when it is lazy evaluated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Till here dataframe is defined and reader object instantiated.

```
scala> spark.read.format("csv").option("header",true).option("inferschema",true)
res2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader = org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@7aead157
```

when you actually say load.

`res2.load('/spark_df_data/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/retail-data/by-day/2011-12-19.csv')` and the file doesnt exist...... **is execution time.(that means it has to check the data source and then it has to load the data from csv)**

To get dataframe its checking meta data of hadoop since it will check hdfs whether this file exist or not.

It doesnt then you are getting

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Path does not exist: hdfs://203-249-241:8020/spark_df_data/Spark-The-Definitive-Guide/data/retail-data/by-day/2011-12-19.csv
```

In general

1) RDD/DataFrame lineage will be created and will not be executed is definition time.
2) when load is executed then it will be the execution time.

See the below flow to understand better.

[image]

Conclude : Any traformation (definition time in your way ) will not be executed until action is called (execution time in your way)

Answer (score 1):

Spark is a lazy evolution. However, that doesn't mean It can't verify if file exist of not while loading it.

Lazy evolution happens on DataFrame object, and in order to create dataframe object they need to first check if file exist of not.

Check the following [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L223).

```
@scala.annotation.varargs
  def load(paths: String*): DataFrame = {
    if (source.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT) == DDLUtils.HIVE_PROVIDER) {
      throw new AnalysisException("Hive data source can only be used with tables, you can not " +
        "read files of Hive data source directly.")
    }

    DataSource.lookupDataSourceV2(source, sparkSession.sessionState.conf).map { provider =>
      val catalogManager = sparkSession.sessionState.catalogManager
      val sessionOptions = DataSourceV2Utils.extractSessionConfigs(
        source = provider, conf = sparkSession.sessionState.conf)
      val pathsOption = if (paths.isEmpty) {
        None
      } else {
        val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        Some("paths" -> objectMapper.writeValueAsString(paths.toArray))
      }
```

Comment: thanks, lot, I got your point. but can you please tell where this textbook quote will apply then. "In general, Spark will fail only at job execution time rather than DataFrame definition time—even if, for example, we point to a file that does not exist. This is due to lazy evaluation,"

Comment: check something with metadata. so if you try to filter on column which does not exist. it will work an give you new dataframe.  You can apply some more filter, join on this dataframe and it will won't fail until you will call some action. (i.e. collect, show etc..)